# Can we convert the style attribute value into a dictionary in C#

Tags: c#

I need to update the style attribute values based on some calculations made in the server side, I have passed the style attribute value from client to server as string, now i need to convert it to key value pair so that i can update the style based in the key but can't convert it. any suggestions please.

value sent to server

```
"width:100%;height:100%;"
```

I need to convert this value to a dictionary in key value pairs so i can update the values based on keys or any alternate solution.

Comment: First you need to split the string by `;` (to extract each pair) and then by `:` (to split each pair into key and value). Once you've done that it's easy to create the dictionary entries

Comment: what result you want:  key "width" and value "100%"  + key "height" and value "100%" or key ("width", "height") value ("100%","100%")?

Comment: `Dictionary<string, string> result = source.Split(';').Select(item => item.Split(':')).ToDictionary(pair => pair[0], pair => pair[1]);`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko you forgot to add `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` to `Split`, otherwise code throws `IndexOutOfRangeException` for last empty item

Answer (score 3):

```
var style = "width:100%;height:70%;";
var dic = style.Split(";", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
               .ToDictionary(k => k.Split(":")[0], k => k.Split(":")[1]);
// Output:
//   Key: width, Value: 100%
//   Key: height, Value: 70%
```

Or, as @DmitryBychenko offered (the only thing he forgot is to remove empty entries):

```
var dic = style.Split(";", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
               .Select(s => s.Split(":"))
               .ToDictionary(k => k[0], k => k[1]);
```

Or even Regex :)

```
var dic = Regex.Matches(style, "(.+?):(.+?);")
          .ToDictionary(m => m.Groups[1].Value, m => m.Groups[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the working code of a consoleapp with the separated function that returns the dict from your string, not using LINQ (apart from the .Tolist()) so more readable and understandable for beginners maybe:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp4 {
  class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      string mystr = "width:100%;height:100%;";
      IDictionary<string, string> myDict = getDictFromString(mystr);
      foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> element in myDict) {
        Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", element.Key, element.Value);
      }
      Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static private IDictionary<string, string> getDictFromString(string stringArgument) {
      string[] mysubStr = stringArgument.Split(';');
      IDictionary<string, string> myResultantDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
      foreach (string substr in mysubStr.ToList()) {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(substr)) {
          string key = substr.Split(':')[0];
          string value = substr.Split(':')[1];
          myResultantDict.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, value));
        }
      }
      return myResultantDict;
    }
  }
}
```